# Effect of deniable encryption on willigness to give up secrets under torture

Tags: behavior, stress, self-control

Suppose a person is tortured and can choose to give up secrets or not.

What effect would a situation have in which the person cannot prove that they gave up all their secrets?

Would a person give up all their secrets or keep them to themselves since giving them up would not result in the torture ending? Suppose the information given cannot be verified and the opposing party can therefor not know if the person gave up the relevant secret and the person knows this.

I wrote [a program](https://github.com/Cookie04DE/Sekura) which is capable of hosting multiple independently encrypted filesystems whose existence cannot be proven without the correct password. The idea of the program is that a person under distress would not give up the password(s) since doing so wouldn't improve their situation (there could always be more passwords).

Would this work for an average human?

Comment: I'm not totally sure the exact question you're asking. Such a system might be more secure to rubberhose cryptanalysis, but it would still be vulnerable in scenarios where the torturers know the type of info they want and that their subject likely possesses access to it. Or, in scenarios where the torturers are able to convince via deception that the former is the case, and/or are ultimately willing to torture their subject to death no matter what is divulged.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. I believe that answers to this question, even with expert references, will be based heavily on opinion rather than fact as there would be so many variables involved. Some of which are pointed out by @Feryll. Opinion-based and debate questions are off-topic here

Comment: @Feryll I clarified the scenario and hope the question is more focused now.

Comment: @Chris Rogers I made the question more focused and hope the added details make the question more answerable.